# Web3.py: ValueError when using pending filter

Tags: python, ethereum, cryptocurrency, web3py

I am trying to look up pending transactions in the BEP20 network using web3.py.
As stated in [in this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57201888/different-ways-of-getting-ethereum-txpool-pending-transactions-at-infura-node-vi), one option to do this is using the filter object.
Here is a minimal example that should reproduce my problem:

```py
from web3 import Web3

peer = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(peer))

f = w3.eth.filter('pending')
res = f.get_all_entries()
```

This code results in the ValueError:

```
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'filter not found'}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a crappy Binance Smart Chain public node.

It may or may not support your operations. Apparently it doesn't. We cannot do anything about it.

Please write this question to the Binance support, as Ethereum community cannot help you with nodes run by private parties.